# create, delete folders and cut and copy files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

is there any tutorials to do the following:

- create and delete folders at the main bundle of my application
- remove folders from the Document folder to specific folder
- list all the folders at the main bundle

any suggestion and help please

Answer (score 1):

Read the NSFileManager class reference.

You can get a NSFileManager instance by doing:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

By example you can delete a file by:

```
NSError *error;
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:myPath error:&error];
```

See here the class reference:
[Class Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)